# Android daily notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

How can I cause the Android system to show a notification from my app, at a daily hour?
Do I need a service, and if so how do I handle it
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need a service. You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to get a Broadcast at required time. Listen to it in your [BroadcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and send your Notification there. After Notification was send, register another alarm in it.

Comment: for this you must register another BroadcastReciever and Recieve the "BootCompleted" Broadcast to register a new Alarm. look here how this is done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android