# Firing up a notification at a daily hour

Tags: java, android, notifications

Ok I'm in a sticky situation here.
I decided to make an app for my anniversary that shows a notification with a message every day at 8 a.m. That's it no complicated interface or anything.
Thing is I might have got myself way in over my head since although I'm not very new to programming I am new to android studio and java.
So do you guys know any sites and/or that would help me make this very simple app since I don't really know what to search for?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android daily notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945434/android-daily-notification)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with android-studio IDE...

Comment: You failed to include what you've done so far. If you don't know what to do at all, Google is your friend..

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest starting with the activity [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

Then, have the activity create a [notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) .

Now you probably want to use the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) tocreate a notification every day at a set time.

My guess is that the final activity will have buttons to toggle the repeating alarm (set with AlarmManager) on or off. This alarm will persist even when you close out of the app/activity. When the 'alarm' goes off you can point to a routine that creates the notification.

Having it all working together might be hard (I am a newbie in Android) but these are the core components you would need and taking it one step at a time will help ! If I have time I will try to come up with a skeleton.

Comment: providing code would have helped...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer I'll try that